# cant deploy from vscode to heroku react app

Tags: reactjs

i try to deploy my react project to heroku
but i  get this errors anyone can help me please?

thank you

the errors:

```
    sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! super-market@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the super-market@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Kv5i0/_logs/2020-11-09T20_29_06_355Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `cd client && npm install && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Kv5i0/_logs/2020-11-09T20_29_06_369Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

my scripts:

```
      "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "install-server": "npm install",
    "install-all": "concurrently\"npm run install-client\"\"npm run install-server\"",
    "dev":"concurrently\"npm run client\"\"npm run server\"",
    "heroku-postbuild":"cd client && npm install && npm run build"

  },
```

and in server file

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'))   
  })
}
```

thank u for your help

Comment: `react-scripts: not found`, what's in your dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the build script here

```
"scripts": {
"build":"**********",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "install-server": "npm install",
    "install-all": "concurrently\"npm run install-client\"\"npm run install-server\"",
    "dev":"concurrently\"npm run client\"\"npm run server\"",
    "heroku-postbuild":"cd client && npm install && npm run build"

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to push React apps to Heroku with a node js backend is to use the Heroku Post Build Script
**Follow the steps below**

Add This below snippet to your package.json under the scripts

```js
    scripts{
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix reactFolderName && npm run build --prefix reactFolderName"
}
```

Add this inside the scripts section and they will take care of the build in heroku